# Mysql master to master group replication on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, mysql-group-replication

I configure mysql master to master group replication using following link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-mysql-group-replication-on-ubuntu-16-04

I have connected two different servers by using above link. First server is connected. But second server is not connected, it gives error

I use mysql> START GROUP_REPLICATION; this command to configure second server. But I get following error log

```html
2018-02-07T11:58:01.707051Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'connecting to 11.0.0.35 33061'
2018-02-07T11:58:11.715442Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Timed out while waiting for connection to be established! Cancelling connection attempt. (socket= 78, error=0)'
2018-02-07T11:58:11.715470Z 0 [Warning] Plugin group_replication reported: 'select - Timeout! Cancelling connection...'
2018-02-07T11:58:11.715479Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Connecting socket to address 11.0.0.35 in port 33061 failed with error 115 - Operation now in progress.'
2018-02-07T11:58:11.715515Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to 11.0.0.35:33061 on local port: 33061.'
2018-02-07T11:58:11.715524Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'connecting to 11.0.0.35 33061'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.725696Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Timed out while waiting for connection to be established! Cancelling connection attempt. (socket= 78, error=0)'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.726394Z 0 [Warning] Plugin group_replication reported: 'select - Timeout! Cancelling connection...'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.726406Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Connecting socket to address 11.0.0.35 in port 33061 failed with error 115 - Operation now in progress.'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.726442Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to 11.0.0.35:33061 on local port: 33061.'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.726451Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error connecting to all peers. Member join failed. Local port: 33061'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.726558Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'state 4338 action xa_terminate'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.726578Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'new state x_start'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.726582Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'state 4338 action xa_exit'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.728254Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Exiting xcom thread'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.728263Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'new state x_start'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.728310Z 0 [Warning] Plugin group_replication reported: 'read failed'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.736534Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The member was unable to join the group. Local port: 33061'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.736559Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Destroying SSL'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.736565Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Success destroying SSL'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.736713Z 2 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'auto_increment_increment is reset to 1'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.736720Z 2 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'auto_increment_offset is reset to 1'
2018-02-07T11:58:21.736822Z 7 [Note] Error reading relay log event for channel 'group_replication_applier': slave SQL thread was killed
2018-02-07T11:58:21.738636Z 4 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'The group replication applier thread was killed'
```

Please any one help me to solve this error

Comment: Can you run `telnet` from master to this `11.0.0.35:33061`? It might be the port on the salve is blocked by the firewall.

Comment: This question should be migrated to another website.

Comment: @Subarna did you found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be SELinux?

You can try disabling SELinux by editting: /etc/selinux/config
and change following line: SELINUX=enforcing to: SELINUX=disabled

Reboot your system and try again.